# Using watir-webdriver, how can I click a table row?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, watir, firefox4, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to convert my old watir scripts to use watir-webdriver instead, as that will (eventually) support IE9 and Firefox 4. `$browser.table_row(:id => "account_1").click` is what I used to click the first row of a table on screen in watir/firewatir, but the API for this was modified in watir-webdriver. Now, the code is this: `$browser.table(:class => "sortable")[0].click` which should grab the first row of the table then click it. It seems to be successful, as it continues code execution, but it doesn't actually click the row.

Can someone explain what the right syntax would be in this case?

Here's the source code around the area I want to click:

```
<table class="sortable">
<thead>
    <tr id="">
        <th> </th>
        <th class="sort" > Name </th>
        <th class="sort" > Number </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="account_1" onclick=";$('timer').show();; new Ajax.Request('create_new_account', {asynchronous:false, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){;$('timer').hide();initializeCustomEffects();}})">
        <td></td>
        <td class="sortTd">Test Account</td>
        <td class="sortTd">1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A sample of the page HTML might help in terms of seeing what events things are reacting to, how to identify the row or elements inside it, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is finding the first row of the table, which is inside the `<thead>` and does not have an onclick handler. Try this instead:

```
browser.tr(:id => "account_1").click
```

Here's [a script](https://gist.github.com/929779) that demonstrates the behavior, and [here's](https://gist.github.com/565553) an overview of the revised table API.

Comment: That code didn't work verbatim, but I altered it to `browser.tr(:id => "account_1").fire_event("onclick")` and got the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A Row isn't an HTTP object that would normally respond to a click.  Is there something inside the row like a link that you want to click on, or is the row itself setup using event handling to respond to a particular event such as 'onclick' or 'onmousedown' ??

If the former, try actually clicking on the object within the row.  If the latter then try experimenting with the .fire_event method and different events.

For example:

```
browser.table(:class => "sortable")[0].fire_event("onmousedown")
```

or maybe

```
browser.table(:class => "sortable").row(:index, 0).fire_event("onmousedown")
```

(addendum)   AH now that we have the HTML we can see where the onclick handler is  and as pointed out by Jarib, you were clicking on the header row (which is technically the first row of the table)   To click the thing you want, you need something along the lines of

```
browser.row(:id, "account_1").click
browser.row(:text, /Test Account/).click
browser.table(:class => "sortable").row(:index, 1).fire_event("onclick")
```

(unless your intent is to sort the table, in which case I suspect you need to click a CELL in the first (header) row in order to sort the table on that column.

```
browser.cell(:text, ' Name ').click
```

Comment: I tried both of those, using the onclick event since that's what's shown in the source, but to no avail.